# pagesize and its ratio to 4096

Tags: paging, systems-programming

Are there systems, where minimal page of memory (pagesize) has a size not divisible by 2, or by 1024, 4096?

Can it be 3000 or 3500?

Will any posix program break, if pagesize will be not divisible by 1024?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely assume that pagesize is a power of 2, at least until ternary computers are used.  In practice, modern systems will have a pagesize that is a multiple of 1024.

As for programs breaking, few programs are concerned about pagesize so as long as the kernel is consistent all is well.  If a program did calculations based on pagesize and used headers with macros that assume pagesize is a power of two (truncpage,roundpage) then it would have problems.